# Probability problem where I remove 4 balls without reposition

Tags: probability

One box has 7 white balls, 3 black balls and 3 red balls. We remove four balls without replacement.

What is the probability that there are two white, one black and one red.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: [Multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Numericallyilliterate's Comment or @John's Answer (+1), the answer is
$\frac{{7\choose 2}{3\choose 1}{3\choose 1}}{{13\choose 4}} = 0.2643,$
as computed using R:

```
choose(7,2)*choose(3,1)*choose(3,1)/choose(13,4)
[1] 0.2643357
```

By simulation, letting white be worth 100, black be worth 10, and red be worth 1, we seek total score $211.$ Simulating four draws
a million times, we can expect two (maybe three) place accuracy. We have the following:

```
set.seed(2021)
box = c(rep(100,7), rep(10,3), rep(1,3))
box
[1] 100 100 100 100 100 100 100  10  10  10   1   1   1

x = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(box,4)))
mean(x == 211)
[1] 0.263744      # aprx 0.2643357
2*sd(x==211)/1000
[1] 0.0008813247  # 95% margin of simulation error
```

Comment: +1 for providing an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

1. How many ways can you pick out two white balls from the seven white ones?
2. How many ways to pick out one black ball from the three black ones? (Same for the red balls)
3. How many ways can you pick out four balls from the whole thing, regardless of color?

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Nice outline (+1)